# How to read own pom.xml file at runtime

Tags: java, maven

I need to read my `pom.xml` file at runtime. 
I'm using `maven-model` for reading pom.xml file:

```
final Model model = mavenReader.read(new FileInputStream("pom.xml"));
final List<Dependency> dependencies = model.getDependencies();
dependencies.forEach(dependency -> {
      String version = dependency.getVersion();
      System.out.println(dependency.getArtifactId() + ":" + version);
});
```

If I run this code from IDE all works fine but if I run it in the docker container I get exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: pom.xml (No such file or directory)
```

What I do wrong? Where is `pom.xml` located in `jar` archive?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Which information from the POM do you need at runtime? I would extract that information during the build and put it into a properties file. Then you can read that as resource.

Comment: @JFMeier I need to get info about dependencies that included in my pom.xml file.

Comment: What are you going to do with that information? Print it to the user? Do something with it?

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, I need to print this information in the admin panel.